# How to send an Email of Assertion Result Failure message in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to Jmeter. 
I have a task where I want to send an email of Assertion result failure.
I have an http request where I'm checking the result of an API, and if it contains appropriate response that test is successful. 
Now the problem is if test is failed, I need to send its result (with failure message) via email.
I have configured SMTP Sampler properly, it is sending mails. But I don't know how to send response assertion failure message as message body with that email.
Can Anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) in order to get assertion failure message(s) from the previous sampler.

1. Add Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of SMTP Request sampler
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;

   AssertionResult[] results = prev.getAssertionResults();
   StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
   for (AssertionResult result : results) {
       body.append(result.getFailureMessage());
       body.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
   }
   vars.put("body", body.toString());
   ```
3. Use `${body}` JMeter Variable in the SMTP Request sampler.

Remember that it will work only for assertion failure messages of the **previous** sampler

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Is it possible to use If controller for SMTP Request Sampler? Actually I need to send email only in that case if assertion fails. And if there is success I don't want to send any email. Currently it is sending email in case of success as well with error message as "NULL". Therefore I have used If controller with the condition "${body}" != "null" . But its not working. Could you help me with this here?

Comment: Use the following condition: `!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}`  - it uses pre-defined variable which returns "true" if previous sampler is successful and "false" otherwise. See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) article for details

Comment: Note: If there are multiple thread groups in a single test plan, then each thread group should have SMTP Sampler as a child element. And `IfController` must be parent of SMTP Sampler.

Comment: thanks for this response @DmitriT, please shall the requests being inserted as child of SMTP Sampler?